# Factor this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Can someone factor this for me? $(x^{\frac{n}3}-a^{\frac{n}3})$

I am stuck on it.  Let n be any natural number.

Comment: It depends a bit on what $n$ is. If $n=3$ you get $x-a$. If $n=6$ you get $(x+a)(x-a)$. If $n$ is not a multiple of $3$, this is not a polynomial (per title, but not tag).

Comment: cause I have that, over (x-a) and I am trying to reduce it and I can't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: Because that's about as simple as it gets for arbitrary $n$.

Comment: Maybe you can say what the larger problem is. Are you taking the limit of that fraction as $x\rightarrow a$, for example?

Comment: Note that $$\forall n\in \mathbb N\forall \alpha,\beta\in \mathbb R\left(\alpha^n-\beta^n=(\alpha-\beta)\left(\alpha ^{n-1}+\alpha^{n-2}\beta+\ldots +\alpha\beta^{n-2}+\beta^{n-1}\right)\right).$$ Take $\alpha=x^{1/3}$ and $\beta=a^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment, it looks like you are being asked to find a "difference quotient".  Subject the condition that the numbers being raised to fractional exponents need to be *positive*, you can treat this as

$$ \frac{x^{n/3} \ - \ a^{n/3}}{x \ - \ a } \ = \ \frac{{x^{n/3}} \ - \ a^{n/3}}{(x^{1/3})^3 \ - \ (a^{1/3})^3 } $$

$$ = \ \frac{{x^{n/3}} \ - \ a^{n/3}}{(x^{1/3} \ - \ a^{1/3}) \ \left[ (x^{1/3})^2 \ + \ (x^{1/3})(a^{1/3}) \ + \ (a^{1/3})^2 \right] } \ \ , $$

applying the "difference of two cubes".

Now the issue becomes what positive integer $ \ n \ $ is.  If $ \ n = 1 \ , $ we'll just have

$$  \frac{1}{x^{2/3} \ + \ x^{1/3} \ a^{1/3} \ + \ a^{2/3}  } \ \ , $$

after canceling numerator against denominator factor.  For $ \ n = 2 \ , $ we'd have

$$  \frac{(x^{1/3} \ - \ a^{1/3}) \ ( x^{1/3} \ + \ a^{1/3})}{(x^{1/3} \ - \ a^{1/3}) \ \left[ (x^{1/3})^2 \ + \ (x^{1/3})(a^{1/3}) \ + \ (a^{1/3})^2 \right] } \ \ , $$

$$ = \  \frac{ x^{1/3} \ + \ a^{1/3}}{  x^{2/3} \ + \ x^{1/3} \ a^{1/3} \ + \ a^{2/3} } \ \ , $$

using "difference of two squares" in the numerator first.  You should always be able to cancel the "difference of cube roots" factors between the numerator and denominator, though the expression may cease to be so tidy for large values of $ \ n \ . $